# Suddenly Unable Run Shell Script Function

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

I have a file named 'wpautobuild.sh'. In that file I have a script that automatically sets up a development environment and website on a linux server.

I've been calling a function named `wp_auto_build()` in the script with the following command:

```
$ ./wpautobuild.sh; wp_auto_build --project=abctest1
```

This worked fine up until I closed my terminal session and restarted it. Now when I run that same command I get following error:

```
-jailshell: wp_auto_build: command not found
```

I have no idea why I could run it fine for a while, but now I cannot. Nothing changed in the file. Admittingly, I am not well experienced in writing shell scripts.

Here is wpautobuild.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

###########
# Variables
###########

#Required Variables
#BashRC File
FILE_BASH="$HOME/.bashrc";
FILE_WPAB="$HOME/wpautobuild.sh";

#The parent folder for all your site files
PATH_DEV="/home/wm/public_html";

#MYSQL Variables
MYSQL_UN="someuser";
MYSQL_PW="somepass";

#Repositories
declare -A REPO_PATH;
REPO_PATH[jumpstart]="https://someuser@bitbucket.org/someuser/wp-jumpstart.git";
REPO_PATH[divi]="https://someuser@bitbucket.org/someuser/divilib.git";

declare -A WP_DB_PREFIX;
WP_DB_PREFIX[jumpstart]="wp_";
WP_DB_PREFIX[divi]="wp_";


#Color variables

GREEN="\033[0;32m";
RED="\033[0;31m";
BLUE="\033[0;34m";
NC="\033[0m"; # No Color

BOLD="\e[1m";

WPAB_CHECKED=false;

#configurable variables
PROJECT_NAME="";

BUILD_TYPE="divi";

DB_NAME="";
DB_FILE_NAME="";

DB_SR_SEARCH="";
DB_SR_REPLACE="";

##############
# Functions
##############

####################################
# WP Build Automation
####################################
handle_arguments() {

    ARGUMENTS=($@);

    for i in "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"
        do

            INDEX=`expr index "$i" =`;

            case $i in
                --project*)
                    PROJECT_NAME=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --build*)
                    BUILD_TYPE=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --dbname*)
                    DB_NAME=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --mysqlun*)
                    MYSQL_UN=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --mysqlpw*)
                    MYSQL_PW=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --dbfilename*)
                    DB_FILE_NAME=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --search*)
                    DB_SR_SEARCH=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                --replace*)
                    DB_SR_REPLACE=${i:INDEX};
                ;;
                *)
                    echo -e "${RED}$i is not recognized as an argument.${NC}\n";
                ;;
            esac
    done;

    if [[ -z $DB_NAME ]];
        then
            DB_NAME=$PROJECT_NAME;
    fi

}




wp_auto_build() {

    # The main script that runs all the necessary functions to set up a site
    #
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; determines directory name, domain, and db name
    #
    #  --build      - [optional]
    #               - [values] - jumpstart, divi
    #               - [default] - jumpstart
    #               - determines whether to install wp-jumpstart or divilib
    #
    #  --dbname     - [optional]
    #               - [default] - --project
    #               - determines the name of the database

    TIMESTAMP_START=$( date +%s );
    
    printf "\n\n${BLUE}${BOLD}****************************************\n";
    printf "WP Autobuild Sarting Up...\n";
    printf "****************************************${NC}\n\n";
    

    #check argument number
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  No arguments passed. --project is required.\n";
            return;
    fi

    handle_arguments $@;

    echo ;
    echo "***********************************";
    echo "Checking Current Configuration...";
    echo "***********************************";
    echo ;

    # Check variables
    check_config;
    #checks the return code of check_config to make sure everything is good. If not stop script
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
        then
            return;
        else
            printf "\n${GREEN}Variables are good${NC}\n\n"
    fi

    # Check configure to make sure all commands and dependencies are there
    check_CLI_dependencies;
    #checks the return code of check_CLI_dependencies to make sure everything is good. If not stop script
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
        then
            return;
        else
            printf "\n${GREEN}Dependencies are good${NC}\n\n"
    fi

    WPAB_CHECKED=true;

    echo "Please check the configuration. Type "Y" and then hit [ENTER] to continue; anything else to stop...";
    read CONTINUE;

    if [[ $CONTINUE != "Y" ]]; then
        return
    fi


    printf "\n***********************************\n";
    printf "Starting: WP Auto-Build...\n";
    printf "***********************************\n";

    #Setup subdomain
    setup_subdomain;

    #Setup Build DB
    setup_build_DB;

    #Search and Replace Build DB
    run_SRDB;

    #Update Plugins and Core
    run_wp_update;
    
    # Open in browser
    open_wpab_site;

    TIMESTAMP_END=$( date +%s );

    RUNTIME=$(($TIMESTAMP_END - $TIMESTAMP_START));

    printf "${GREEN}\n";
    printf "***********************************\n";
    printf "Done: WP Auto-Build...\n";
    printf "Time: $RUNTIME secs\n";
    printf "***********************************\n";
    printf "${NC}\n";

}

setup_subdomain() {
    #
    # Adds a directory for the project and adds an alias in bash goto_{--project}.
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; deteremines directory name, domain, and db name
    #

    # if false, then we are running the function individually and need to supply arguments, handle arguments and check variables
    if [ $WPAB_CHECKED == 'false' ]
        then
            handle_arguments $@;

            # ########################
            # ADD INDIVIDUAL CHECKS
            # ########################
    fi

    printf "${GREEN}Setting up subdomain for site...\n";
    printf "************************************${NC}\n";

    # Create subdomain using cpanel api
    uapi --user=someuser SubDomain addsubdomain domain=$PROJECT_NAME rootdomain=somedomain.com dir=%2Fpublic_html%2F$PROJECT_NAME

}


setup_build() {
    # Clones the build repository, deletes the git and then reinitializes it.
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; deteremines directory name, domain, and db name
    #
    #  --build      - [optional]
    #               - [values] - jumpstart, divi
    #               - [default] - jumpstart
    #               - determines whether to install wp-jumpstart or divilib


    # if false, then we are running the function individually and need to supply arguments, handle arguments and check variables
    if [ $WPAB_CHECKED == 'false' ]
        then
            handle_arguments $@;

            # ########################
            # ADD INDIVIDUAL CHECKS
            # ########################
    fi

    printf "\n${GREEN}Cloning $BUILD_TYPE repository...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}";

    cd "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME";

    echo "";

    #Clone Repository
    git clone ${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]} "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME";

    #Remove repository .git so we can reinitialize it
    rm -rf "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME/.git";

}

setup_build_DB() {
    #
    # Sets up WP wp-config.php file and WP database based on the file in .dev/sql
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; deteremines directory name, domain
    #
    # --dbname      - [required]
    #               - name of the databsae;
    #
    # --build       - [required]
    #               - [values] - jumpstart, divi
    #               - [default] - jumpstart
    #               - database table prefix
    #
    # --mysqlun     - [optional]
    #               - override default MYSQL_UN;
    #
    # --mysqlpw     - [optional]
    #               - override default MYSQL_PW;
    #

    # if false, then we are running the function individually and need to supply arguments, handle arguments and check variables
    if [ $WPAB_CHECKED == 'false' ]
        then
            handle_arguments $@;

            # ########################
            # ADD INDIVIDUAL CHECKS
            # ########################
    fi

    cd "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME";

    printf "\n${GREEN}Creating database...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";

    #create db
    uapi --user=someuser Mysql create_database name=wm_$PROJECT_NAME
    
    printf "\n${GREEN}Assigning user to database...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    
    #assign user
    uapi --user=someuser Mysql set_privileges_on_database user=dbuser database=wm_$PROJECT_NAME privileges=DELETE,UPDATE,CREATE,ALTER
    
    printf "\n${GREEN}Importing database from .dev/sql directory...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    
    if [ $BUILD_TYPE == 'jumpstart' ]; then
        wp db import "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME/.dev/sql/wpjs-c8631c0.sql";
    elif [ $BUILD_TYPE == 'divi' ]; then
        wp db import "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME/.dev/sql/divilib.sql";
    fi

}

run_SRDB() {
    #
    # Ruin SRDB on the database
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; deteremines directory name, domain
    #
    # --dbname      - [required]
    #               - name of the databsae;
    #
    # --build       - [required]
    #               - [values] - jumpstart, divi
    #               - [default] - jumpstart
    #               - database table prefix
    #
    # --mysqlun     - [optional]
    #               - override default MYSQL_UN;
    #
    # --mysqlpw     - [optional]
    #               - override default MYSQL_PW;

    # if false, then we are running the function individually and need to supply arguments, handle arguments and check variables
    if [ $WPAB_CHECKED == 'false' ]
        then
            handle_arguments $@;

            # ########################
            # ADD INDIVIDUAL CHECKS
            # ########################
    fi

    printf "\n${GREEN}Running Search & Replace for URL...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";


    #cd "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME/srdb";

    if [ $BUILD_TYPE == 'jumpstart' ]; then
        wp search-replace 'wpjs.local' "$PROJECT_NAME.somedomain.com"
    elif [ $BUILD_TYPE == 'divi' ]; then
        wp search-replace 'divilib.local' "$PROJECT_NAME.somedomain.com"
    fi
}

run_wp_update() {
    #
    # Update Wordpress and Plugins
    #
    # Arguments
    # --project     - [required]
    #               - name of the project; deteremines directory name, domain
    #
    # --build       - [required]
    #               - [values] - jumpstart, divi
    #               - [default] - jumpstart
    #               - database table prefix


    # if false, then we are running the function individually and need to supply arguments, handle arguments and check variables
    if [ $WPAB_CHECKED == 'false' ]
        then
            handle_arguments $@;

            # ########################
            # ADD INDIVIDUAL CHECKS
            # ########################
    fi

    cd "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME";
    
    #Update Core
    
    printf "\n${GREEN}Updating WP Core...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    
    wp core update;

    #Update All Plugins
    
    printf "\n${GREEN}Updating WP Plugins...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    
    wp plugin update --all;
    
    #Update All Themes
    
    printf "\n${GREEN}Updating WP Themes...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    
    wp theme update --all;
    
}


check_config() {
    WPAB_STATUS=true;

    echo "Required Variables...";
    echo "***********************************";

    #Project Name
    if [ -z "$PROJECT_NAME" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  PROJECT_NAME is empty. This must be passed with --project.\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else

            #Site files
            if [ -d "$PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME" ]
                then
                    printf "${RED}[FAILED]  $PATH_DEV/$PROJECT_NAME is already a project directory.${NC}\n";
                    WPAB_STATUS=false;
                else
                    printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   PROJECT_NAME:       $PROJECT_NAME${NC}\n";
            fi

    fi

    #DB Name
    if [ -z "$DB_NAME" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  DB_NAME is empty. ($DB_NAME)\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   DB_NAME:        $DB_NAME${NC}\n";
    fi

    #Build Type
    if [ $BUILD_TYPE != 'jumpstart' ] && [ $BUILD_TYPE != 'divi' ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  BUILD_TYPE can olny be /"jumpstart/" or /"divi/" ($BUILD_TYPE).\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   BUILD_TYPE:         $BUILD_TYPE${NC}\n";
    fi


    #.bashrc
    if [ ! -f "$FILE_BASH" ]
        then
            printf "\n${RED}[FAILED]    FILE_BASH does not exist ($FILE_BASH). This variable must point to your .bashrc file.${NC}\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "\n${GREEN}[SUCCESS]     FILE_BASH:      $FILE_BASH${NC}\n";
    fi

    #Site files
    if [ ! -d "$PATH_DEV" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  PATH_DEV does not exist ($PATH_DEV). This variable is the path to the PARENT of your sites' directory.${NC}\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   PATH_DEV:       $PATH_DEV${NC}\n";
    fi

    #check repositories
    if [ -z "${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]}" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE] is empty. This variable should be a reference to the build repository. (${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]})${NC}\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]:     ${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]}${NC}\n";
    fi

    #MYSQL Credentials
    if [ -z "$MYSQL_UN" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  MYSQL_UN is empty ($MYSQL_UN). This variable must be set to a MYSQL Username.\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   MYSQL_UN:       $MYSQL_UN${NC}\n";
    fi

    if [ -z "$MYSQL_PW" ]
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  MYSQL_PW is empty ($MYSQL_PW). This variable must be set to a MYSQL Password.\n";
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   MYSQL_PW:       $MYSQL_PW${NC}\n";
    fi


    echo ;
    echo ;
    echo "Optional Variables...";
    echo "***********************************";

    #Stop script
    if [ $WPAB_STATUS == false ]
        then
            echo ;
            printf "${RED}Something went wrong. Check the output. Killing process...${NC}\n";
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    fi
}

check_CLI_dependencies() {
    WPAB_STATUS=true;

    #check git
    printf "\nChecking git...\n";
    echo "**********************************************";
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v git)" ];
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  git is NOT accessible.${NC}\n\n" >&2
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   git is accessible.${NC}\n\n";

            #check access to wp-jumpstart
            printf "Checking: Checking access to ${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]}\n";
            git ls-remote "${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]}" --exit-code;

            # ls-remote returns anything other than 0, then you cannot access
            if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];
                then
                    printf "${RED}[FAILED]  Unable to read from ${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]}${NC}\n\n";
                    WPAB_STATUS=false;
                else
                    printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   Access to ${REPO_PATH[$BUILD_TYPE]} is good.${NC}\n\n";
            fi

    fi


    #check mysql
    printf "\nChecking mysql...\n";
    echo "**********************************************";
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v mysql)" ];
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  mysql is NOT accessible.${NC}\n" >&2;
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   myqsl is accessible.${NC}\n";

            # check_mysql_access returns anything other than 0, then you cannot access
            if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];
                then
                    printf "${RED}[FAILED]  Unable to connect to MYSQL. Either credentials are not valid (UN: $MYSQL_UN PW: $MYSQL_PW) or MYSQL is not running. ${NC}\n\n";
                    WPAB_STATUS=false;
                else
                    printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   Access to MYSQL is good.${NC}\n\n";
            fi
    fi


    #check wp
    printf "\nChecking wp-cli...\n";
    echo "**********************************************";
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v wp)" ];
        then
            printf "${RED}[FAILED]  wp-cli is not installed correctly.${NC}\n" >&2
            WPAB_STATUS=false;
        else
            printf "${GREEN}[SUCCESS]   wp-cli is good.${NC}\n"

    fi

    #Stop script
    if [ $WPAB_STATUS == false ]
        then
            echo ;
            printf "${RED}Something went wrong. Check the output. Killing process...${NC}\n";
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    fi
}

#open site url in default browser
open_wpab_site () {
    printf "\n${GREEN}Launching Website...\n";
    printf "*****************************************${NC}\n";
    printf "Opening url in default browser...";
    
    start https://$PROJECT_NAME.somedomain.com
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the command 'source' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161291/what-does-the-command-source-do)

Comment: You should let the script call the relevant functions itself, so you can do e.g. `./wpautobuild.sh build --project=abctest1`. It worked because you at some point ran `. ./wpautobuild.sh` aka `source ./wpautobuild.sh` and you can keep doing that, but it's a bit weird and hacky

Comment: Wow! Yes it does. 'source' worked like a charm. I'm back up and running. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the script from the CLI, which actually spawns a sub-shell, runs your script and then terminates. When it terminates, all created environment variables and functions simply get thrown away. They never arrive in your *current* shell, so you can not call a function from your shell that's defined in your script.

If you want to define functions that are available in your *current* environment, you would need to `source` the script defining these or, since this is conforming to POSIX, use `.`. Usually, when defining functions that shall behave like custom built-in commands, you add the function definition to `.bashrc` or something similar or you `source` a script doing that from there.

I was actually wondering why you were able to call your `wp_auto_build` for some time. I assume you were testing your script by pasting it from your favorite text editor directly into the shell. This **does** define variables and functions in your *current* environment for sure.